# Reverse items in generic List

Tags: java, generics, collections

I need to swap the items back to front on a generic class that inherits from List.
The items to swap can be of any type ofcourse.
I though of doing this by pushing the contents onto a Stack of the same type and pop them afterwards.

I get the following error :
    push (capture) in Stack cannot be applied to (capture)

Code :

```
static <T extends List<?>> void swapList(T list){
    Stack<?> temp = new Stack<>();
    //temp = list.forEach(Collectors.toCollection(Stack::new));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++){
        temp.push(list.get(i)); //list.get(i) produces the error
    }
    temp.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: `Collections.reverse()` not working?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer That was my first thought but the teacher told me I can't use shortcuts

Comment: other shortcut: copy and paste the code from `Collections.reverse()`

Comment: ^ That's like adding something to a report from Wikipedia, then taking the source that Wikipedia used :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add something to a collection which has an `extends` bound (`?` is a shorthand for `? extends Object`). For type safety, the compiler won't let you call a *consumer method* on such a collection (something which accepts a parameter of the type variable's type). This is because it could be a `Stack<Integer>`, `Stack<Foo>`, not just a `Stack<T>`.

The easiest thing to do here is to change your `Stack`'s type to

```
Stack<Object> temp = new Stack<>();
```

You don't actually care about what you're adding to it; and you don't care about returning a reversed `List<T>`.

In fact, your type variable is redundant. You can simply declare the method as:

```
static void swapList(List<?> list) {
```

But if you *do* want a type variable, declare it as a variable representing the list's element type, so you can use it as a bound on your Stack too:

```
static <T> void swapList(List<T> list){
  Stack<T> temp = new Stack<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter that T extends List. What matters is the type of objects inside that list.

So most likely, your method signature should rather look like:

```
static <T> void swapList(List<T> list){
```

Meaning: it shouldn't (and doesn't) matter to this method that a subclass of List is coming in. The generic part should be about the thingies **inside** that list.

Comment: @AndyTurner Well. It was a [tough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357021/reputable-people-keep-answering-duplicates-whats-the-solution) week. It is hard to be a reputation addict on cold turkey ;-)